# how to efficiently pass the rows of a column of a datafame to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
mydic = {'mara': 1, 'juli':2}
```

I have dataframe like this:

```
data = [['mara', 10], ['sara', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
df['id'] = df['Name'].apply(mydic)
```

so the rsult would look like this:

```
Name   Age  id
mara   10    1
juli   14    2
sara   15    null
```

I know the code I have written above does not work since I have not passed any key to the dictionary but not sure how can I accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map

```
df=df.assign(ids=df.Name.map(mydic))
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `df.assign`. works like a charm.